# "ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension"

Tags: python, machine-learning

how to use the below code on 3 columns of X_train data. The error

> "ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension"

was found on execution of the below code with 3 columns of X_train data.

```
# Visualising the Training set results
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('K-NN (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Estimated Salary')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The error comes from `classifier.predict`, so it has nothing to do with numpy or matplotlib. Hence please use the correct tags and make sure it's clear what `classifier` is.

Comment: classifier is knn classifier

Answer (score 2):

The number of dimensions your feature vector has must be the same during training and for prediction. If you want to predict using 3 columns then the model must also be trained with 3.

Comment: X_train.shape= (87482, 3)

Comment: Assuming your using keras, `query data dimension must match training data dimension` is being thrown due to your query value for `classifier.predict()` not being in the form of `[ x, 3]`. Can you print the shape for the array you're parsing to it?